# Choosing between XML data provider and SQL with Ninject from a config file

Tags: .net, ninject

I need a general Ninject usage advice.

I have an Interface `IDataProvider` and two implementations `XmlProvider:IDataProvider` and `OracleSqlProvider:IDataProvider`.

I want to use Ninject to instantiate an interface implementation, given that it is defined somehow in app.config.

Questions:

1. Which is the best way to define what particular implementation to user in app.config?
2. Is there an automatic way for Ninject 2 to read the preferred bindings from code?
3. What if my XML provider needs no parameters in the constructor, whereas SQL needs a connection string. How does this affect my declaration in app.config and further instantiation in Ninject Module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best way in your sceanrio is to implement a Provider that gets the information from the app.config and returns the appropriate provider. This also allows to pass the connection string.

Comment: How does this relate to Ninject? If you are referring to a common class as a Provider, then it would be a dependency injection by hand. I am willing to use Ninject though.

Comment: Provider is a Ninject class. Usage: Bind<IX>().ToProvider<XProvider>()
and class XProvider : Provider<IX> ....

Answer (score 0):

See [Ninject.Extensions.Xml](http://www.ninject.org/extensions), i think that is what you need.